# Which is the correct word choice?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, grammaticality

I have a very positive view regarding/of muslims.

Are "regarding" and "of" both usable in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either "view of X" or "view regarding X" is correct, and both convey the same meaning.

From the standpoint of style, I find "regarding" a bit pretentious, but that is merely personal preference.